# Use same file name as pypi package in python

Tags: python, import

How can i have a file named `socket.py` but still import the real socket package?

**socket.py**

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()
print(s)
```

**output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\socket.py", line 1, in <module>
    import socket
  File "C:\socket.py", line 4, in <module>
    s = socket.socket()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I tried using `importlib` but with no success...

**socket.py**

```
import importlib
socket = importlib.import_module('socket')

s = socket.socket()
print(s)
```

**output:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\socket.py", line 2, in <module>
    socket = importlib.import_module('socket')
  File "C:\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\socket.py", line 4, in <module>
    s = socket.socket()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

you have 2 options.

- (recommended) Simply use another name for your module, to avoid confusion and possible failures, for example putting __socket.py
- in case you want to continue having two modules with the same name and you want to import yours and the other, you must use __import__ as follows

```
import importlib 

socket = importlib.import_module("socket") #Python module
```

any questions do not hesitate to ask me.

Comment: Thank you! I actually want to use the same name as the python module but it doesn't import the real pypi package when i use `import socket`. As shown in my question I want to use the real python module but it doen't work.

Comment: my English is not that good :), update the answer in case you don't want to change the name. let me know if it works for you

Comment: Thank you but it didn't work, I updated my question so you can see.